# What is the difference between this and this.each in jquery plugin pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am reading this jQuery plugin pattern: https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.extend-skeleton.js  What I don't understand is what is the purpose of calling each function on `this` in the return statement? That is in place of :

```
    ;(function($){
        $.fn.extend({
            pluginName: function( options ) {

                this.defaultOptions = {};

                var settings = $.extend({}, this.defaultOptions, options);

                return this.each(function() {

                    var $this = $(this);

                });

            }

        });

    })(jQuery);
```

if I simply return `this` as:

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        pluginName: function( options ) {

            this.defaultOptions = {};

            var settings = $.extend({}, this.defaultOptions, options);

            return this;

        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Both work same. As far as I understand `this` acts as the selected element in the plugin. For example if I have three divs with class `test` and I do:

```
$(".test").pluginName(); // returns an array of three div elements in both plugin styles
```

As far as I understand `$(".test")` gives an array of three dom elements and pluginName is called three times for `$(".test").pluginName();` and the three returned values are pushed in an array which at last is returned.

So pleas explain why they use `this.each()` not `this` in return statement?

Comment: As the js filename indicates, that's just a skeleton to build upon. Certainly if there's nothing to do for each element, then you don't need `.each()`. But if there's nothing to do, that'll make for a very uninteresting plugin.

Comment: You use `.each()` if you need to do different things for each item in the collection.

Comment: @epascarello Could you explain with some example? E.g. if I want to alert only those `.test` which have `pop` class then would I use `this.each` in return?

Comment: `this` in that context is a collection. You use it like any other jquery collection. you can use .each, .map, .attr, .html, .whateverjqeurymethodorpluginyouwant or none at all.

Comment: The `this.each() ` is just like `$(".foo").each()`, do you know why you would use each() in that case?

Comment: @epascarello Yes I know I use each to iterate over an array or jquery returned array of elements. For example for json data I had to use it. But why is it needed in plugin pattern? `return this` already returns an array of elements. And what is the purpose of `var $this = $(this);`?

Comment: If you're doing nothing within it, there's no purpose. Just like any other time you're using a jquery method. You wouldn't call .attr() if you didn't want to get/set an attribute.

Comment: @KevinB In what circumstances I would need to do something in `each`? If that can be done without `each` then why should I use `each`?

Comment: look at the source of any jquery plugin.

Comment: @KevinB I am looking at two plugins. I'll update question soon with real example of no difference between `return this` and `return this.each`

Comment: look. there is no difference, as i have said before. read my comments. read the docs. this.each() returns this. you use this.each if you need to do something to each element individually that you can't do with a single method on the whole collection. that has nothing to do with what you return from the plugin.

Comment: you could even use 'return "hello world"' and it would still be a jquery plugin

Comment: @KevinB But that would prevent chaining. I saw other plugin it used `return this.each(function(){ //plugin logic here })`. Although it can be `this.each(function(){ //plugin logic here });  return this`.

Comment: that's my point. you can code the plugin to do what you need it to do and return what you want it to return, in the way you want to return it.

Comment: @KevinB From earlier comments it seemed `return each` is necessary for certain cases and not using it will make the plugin unuseful.

Comment: it is necessary if you want to both iterate over the elements and return them in one expression. Why separate it if it doesn't need to be?

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand $(".test") gives an array of three dom elements and pluginName is called three times for $(".test").pluginName(); and the three returned values are pushed in an array which at last is returned.

This is not correct. `pluginName()` is called once, with this set to the jQuery object corresponding to the three DOM elements. So `this.each()` is used so that you loop over the jQuery object and do whatever you need to do for each one.